# How to let user only view pdf file in web page and not to download?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want to restrict user to only view the pdf file and not able to download .
Is this possible ?
if yes please help.

Comment: you could do it but where is the point of doing that? I can copy paste anything from your site and even if you make it an jpg or whatever I could screenshot it and then run a program to make the image a normal text file...

Comment: you realise that from a technical point of view, if a user has viewed some content on your site, be it HTML, JPG, PDF, whatever, then actually it has already been downloaded to their device, because the browser downloaded it in order to display it - the web is not some remote desktop functionality, it actually fetches all the site content in order to let the user see it. Once it's on their machine, the boat has already sailed. If you don't want something to be downloaded, don't put it on the internet.

Comment: You can do the things suggested in the duplicate but they're only UI hacks to make it harder for users. Nothing you can do can 100% prevent the user from saving the information if they know what to do - it's already on the device in some form, either in downloads or temp files, or there will be a URL to it in the page source or viewable in the developer tools of the browser which could be used to download it separately. And then there's the situation where if the user doesn't have a PDF plugin in their browser, the file could be offered for download anyway, outside your control.